# Python requests html printed response in array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to check if link contains `http` and print the URL.

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import sys

link = "http://www.tvil.me/view/93/4/8/v/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99_%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%99_IZombie.html"
enter_episodes = HTMLSession().get(link)
page = enter_episodes.html
s = page.xpath("//*[@class='view-watch-button']/a")
for l in s:
    link = l.links
    if link != "set()":
        print(link)
```

Response:

```
{'http://streamcloud.eu/ga4m4hizbrfb/iZombie.S04E08.HDTV.x264-SVA.mkv.html'}
{'http://uptostream.com/77p26f7twwhe'}
set()
{'https://clipwatching.com/aog2ni06rzjt/rrFhepnbFfpt6xg.mkv.html'}
set()
[Finished in 1.7s]
```

I tried to delete the `set()` response and to get only the link without `{'` and `'}`.

Comment: use `pop()` in a set to get the full result; And you must print `set()` somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure the set has a length of more than one, and then pop it:

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import sys

link = "http://www.tvil.me/view/93/4/8/v/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99_%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%99_IZombie.html"
enter_episodes = HTMLSession().get(link)
page = enter_episodes.html
s = page.xpath("//*[@class='view-watch-button']/a")
for l in s:
    link = l.links
    if len(link) > 0: # make sure it has a value
        print(link.pop()) # get the last value (in your case, the only one)
```